# Importing the results of Visual Studio Code Coverage into SonarQube when using MSBuildSonarRunner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am not able to see Unit Test Coverage information on my project's dashboard. 
I use the "Unit Tests Coverage" widget.

I searched through the Sonar documentation as well as checked out other questions on stackoverflow - but unfortunately not found anything that helped me with my issue.

I have a .sln file that includes a few C# projects.

I am using the MSBuildSonarRunner to analyze the sln and import to SonarQube 5.1.2.

Everything is done through command prompt, though I do plan to integrate with TFS 2013 shortly.

I am running the commands detailed in the SonarQube documentation link, under the "Visual Studio Code Coverage" section.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Code+Coverage+Results+Import

I use the "MSBuild command prompt for VS2015"

Specifically for my project, these commands are

---

```
cd C:\SONARTrial\Solutions
"C:\SONAR\sonar-runner-msbuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /name:SonarTest /key:SonarTestKey /version:1.0 /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\TestResults\*.trx" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\CoverageResults\*.coveragexml" 

msbuild soptrial.sln
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /Logger:trx "proj1.Tests\bin\Debug\proj1.Tests.dll" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /Logger:trx "proj2.Tests\bin\Debug\proj2.Tests.dll"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"CoverageResults\proj1.coverage" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "proj1.Tests\bin\Debug\proj1.Tests.dll" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"CoverageResults\proj1.coveragexml" "CoverageResults\proj1.coverage" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"CoverageResults\proj2.coverage" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "proj2.Tests\bin\Debug\proj2.Tests.dll" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"CoverageResults\proj2.coveragexml" "CoverageResults\proj2.coverage" 

"C:\SONAR\sonar-runner-msbuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe"  end > a.txt
```

---

I confirmed that the files are present in the folders.

The below 2 statements are present in the output fle "a.txt" for each project in my sln (ie output by msbuild end)

```
17:08:55.999 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\CoverageResults\proj1.coveragexml
17:08:56.161 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\CoverageResults\proj2.coveragexml
```

Also, in the end of "a.txt", it has the following lines

```
17:09:49.175 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor@d3b82e4
17:09:49.175 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\CoverageResults\proj1.coveragexml
17:09:49.195 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\CoverageResults\proj1.coveragexml
17:09:49.305 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor@d3b82e4 (done) | time=130ms
17:09:49.305 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor@6ee3fc35
17:09:49.305 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\TestResults\a_b 2015-09-30 17_08_28.trx
17:09:49.305 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file C:\SonarTrial\Solutions\TestResults\a_b 2015-09-30 17_08_29.trx
17:09:49.325 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor@6ee3fc35 (done) | time=20ms
```

It looks like the runner is able to find the files, but parsing them yields no coverage results to display on the dashboard...

The unit tests count is displayed on the dashboard but coverage is blank..

Help!!!

Comment: Could you verify that the absolute paths contained in the code coverage report matches the files you are analyzing in SonarQube?

Comment: Moreover, could you also check that you do get some code coverage in these reports?

Comment: Also, try to pass the following parameter `/d:sonar.verbose=true` to the begin phase of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner to see the DEBUG level log information as well, which might be more helpful